# MySQL Left Join running very slow, splitting into 2 queries is much faster

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, left-join

When I run my query with a `LEFT JOIN`, it takes 20 seconds. When I split it into 2 queries, it runs in 4 seconds. However, as you can imagine, this makes it very difficult to display the results in a certain order. **What is wrong with my initial query, and can I combine the 2 into 1?**

`Table1` has ~400,000 rows and Table2 has ~200,000 rows.

`Field3` is the primary key in `Table2`, and is indexed in `Table1`.

The queries return approx ~100k rows.

```
SELECT Table1.Field1, Table2.Field4
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN
        Table2 USING (Field3)
WHERE Table1.Field1 = 'Example'
```

When I run the query as written, it takes on average 20 seconds to run. But if I run the query without the `LEFT JOIN`, and run a 2nd query to get that data, everything runs in total in about 4 seconds.

```
SELECT Table1.Field1, Table1.Field3
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Field1 = 'Example'

//PHP
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if (!$first)
    {
        $field3Values .= ",";   
    }
    $field3Values .= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($row['Field3']) . "'";  
    $first = false;
}

//Now run the 2nd query
SELECT Field4
FROM People
WHERE Field3 IN (" . $field3Values . ")
```

**Edit:** As requested, the `EXPLAIN` from the first query:
[image]

Comment: have you tries ON instead of USING?

Comment: @raheelshan Yes, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Is table1 indexed by `Field1` ?

Comment: Please post an `EXPLAIN` of the single query.

Comment: @G-Nugget Not sure how that helps, but I added it to the question

Comment: @danihp No - the actual query selects a number of fields from `Table1`, most of which are not indexed. But both the slow and the quick query are selecting the same fields from `Table1`.

Comment: Adding an index on `Table1.Field1` will help significantly.

Comment: @G-Nugget In my real query, I'm selecting almost the entire table. Are you saying I should put an index on all these fields? Also, I'm selecting the same fields from `Table1` in the slow query as I am in the fast query--so how could this be my issue?

Comment: @John The index will make the filter of the rows on `Table1` much faster.  The index doesn't need to cover all of the fields you're selecting.  If you will also be filtering by more than just `Field1` on `Table1`, you might want to add those fields to the index.

Comment: @G-Nugget Alright, thank you--I understand how that will make BOTH queries faster. But that doesn't explain why the slow query is so much slower than the fast queries, or how I can make the fast queries into 1 query.

Comment: @John I'm not sure why there is so much of a difference in the queries, but the single query basically is the two queries combined into one (unless you want to do an `IN(subquery)`, which is not optimal and more difficult).  With the index on `Table1.Field1`, the single query should be fast.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26189/discussion-between-g-nugget-and-john)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John and I figured this out in a chat.  The single query was slow because the query optimizer wasn't selecting a good index for `Table1`.   By adding `FORCE INDEX (Field1)` to the query, the index on `Table1.Field1` was used to filter the results instead of doing a full table scan.  We're not completely sure why the two query approach was running faster, but my guess is that for some reason the query optimizer was using the index in the first of the single queries, but not in the single.